# How to make unit test methods shorter

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I have some unit tests. Like this:

```
[TestFixture]
public class Tests
{
    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
    }
}
```

But it looks like almost the same code. Is it possible to write this shorter?

I am using NUnit testing framework.

And this is the code:

```
public class Parcel
{
    
 //Some code
    
}
```

It works now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [TestCase](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/testcase.html) instead of Test attribute to run the same test code with different data, e.g.

```
[TestCase(0.02m, "Name: parcel - Postal code 2582Cd - Weight 0,02 - Value 0,0 - Department Mail")]
[TestCase(2m, "Name: parcel - Postal code 2582Cd - Weight 2 - Value 0,0 - Department Regular")]
public void ParcelsWithSpecificWeightShouldBeSpecificToString(decimal weight, string expected)
{
    var parcel = new Parcel { Name="parcel", PostalCode = "2582Cd", Weight = weigth, Value = 0.0m };
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, parcel.ToString());
}
```

But in fact you are testing the `Department` property, so I would recommend not to test `parcel.ToString()`, but `parcel.Department`:

```
[TestCase(0.02m, "Mail")]
[TestCase(2m, "Regular")]
public void ParcelsWithSpecificWeightShouldBeSpecificDepartment(decimal weight, string expected)
{
    var parcel = new Parcel { Name="parcel", PostalCode = "2582Cd", Weight = weigth, Value = 0.0m };
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, parcel.Department);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but also the value. And in one test case it is a mixed version: so weight and value.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to reduce the number of lines in your testing methods - you could perform your parcel initializations in Setup() as parcel1, parcel2....parcelN.

However this will still use the same number of lines of code as your current setup, it will just be outside of the test methods. Its not easy to further optimize 2 line methods, to be honest.